# How can the same 16kb genericons.css file be so much slower on mobile than desktop? And what can I do about it?

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, pagespeed

My wordpress theme uses genericons which are contained in a 16kb file. This is no problem for desktop - according to PageSpeed insights it takes only 230ms. But on mobile that same file takes 1230 ms to load!

I have a similar problem with my childtheme css file. It's 1kb which loads in 150ms on desktop but 480ms on mobile.  Why the huge gap and what can I do about it?

Another css issue - I just started using the Elementor plug-in, which includes font-awesome css. My theme already includes font-awesome in its own f-a css file. How can I stop the css file from being loaded twice?

I tried adding some code to dequeue the genericons but it didn't work. The `genericons.css` still shows up as a drag on my mobile PageSpeed.

Here's the code:

```
function dequeue_my_css()
{
wp_dequeue_style('genericons'); 
wp_deregister_style('genericons');
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_my_css', 100);
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide about the genericons or combining the two font-awesome `css` files.